# Can non-workspace users use service accounts for google's oauth2 calls (Google Sign In)?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-signin, gcloud

I'm having trouble finding a decent tutorial on how to set up a service account so that my personal website can use Google Sign In. What role does the service account need? I don't have google workspace (yet).

I'm currently using "Application Default Credentials (ADC)" from `gcloud auth application-default login` w/ the project in "test" mode...

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Start a service account and let it resolve a user's email address from their authtoken i get from google sign in

Comment: You cannot use a service account for Google Sign In. Edit your post with improved details on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I am with @JohnHanley with this. I think you are better off starting with this link: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in using Google Identity. This should help you get further.

Comment: It's out of date, it says so right at the top, and I've read it several times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fundamentally, you don't need to use any auth outside of the client id associated with your project for the basic functions of Google Sign In.

I know this because I deleted all of my auth keys/json files, and unless they are stored somewhere, everything still functions. This seems to be true when using the golang google.golang.org/api/idtoken library to process Google Sign In user flows.